# Rails ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)) during insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2.0.rc2 and ruby 1.9.3p0

I have a quotes table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "quotes" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "quote_value" float, "quote_note" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
```

When I create a new quote via http://localhost:3000/quotes/new, I get the error

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

and

```
app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

The following is from development.log

```
 Started POST "/quotes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-10 18:58:11 +0100
Processing by QuotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3l5KzYrwIOf84P3Y4JF1/iV1Sx+Uf4rfq3y6iUUinSw=", "quote"=>{"quote_value"=>"1", "quote_note"=>"hello"}, "commit"=>"Create Quote"}
quote is : #<Quote:0x324bbb8>
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.8ms)  INSERT INTO "quotes" ("created_at", "quote_note", "quote_value", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 10 Jan 2012 17:58:11 UTC +00:00], ["quote_note", "hello"], ["quote_value", "1"], ["updated_at", Tue, 10 Jan 2012 17:58:11 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.5ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Is it because of the formatted values in the Insert query?

Thanks

Update: The quotes_controller.rb file

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /quotes
  # GET /quotes.json
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @quotes }
    end
  end

  # GET /quotes/1
  # GET /quotes/1.json
  def show
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @quote }
    end
  end

  # GET /quotes/new
  # GET /quotes/new.json
  def new
    @quote = Quote.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @quote }
    end
  end

  # GET /quotes/1/edit
  def edit
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /quotes
  # POST /quotes.json
  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(params[:quote])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @quote, status: :created, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /quotes/1
  # PUT /quotes/1.json
  def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.update_attributes(params[:quote])
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /quotes/1
  # DELETE /quotes/1.json
  def destroy
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to quotes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Update 2: added models

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :cust_email, :presence => true

  has_many :quotes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :brokers, :through => :quotes
end

class Broker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :requests, :through => :quotes
end

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker
  belongs_to :request
end
```

Update 3: The following is the Full Trace

```
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:190:in `quote_value'
vendor/bundle/gems/activemodel-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:143:in `attribute_change'
vendor/bundle/gems/activemodel-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `block in changes'
vendor/bundle/gems/activemodel-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `map'
vendor/bundle/gems/activemodel-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `changes'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:23:in `save'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:50:in `block in create'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:45:in `create'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__798983255__process_action__126235889__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:119:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:119:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:199:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:242:in `block in action'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/journey-1.0.0.rc4/lib/journey/router.rb:60:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/gems/journey-1.0.0.rc4/lib/journey/router.rb:48:in `each'
vendor/bundle/gems/journey-1.0.0.rc4/lib/journey/router.rb:48:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:570:in `call'
vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/omniauth-966a4653a5fd/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call!'
vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/omniauth-966a4653a5fd/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:148:in `call'
vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/omniauth-966a4653a5fd/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:28:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__429521786__call__490392356__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:63:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can we see the code from `app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb`

Comment: @ctcherry question updated, thanks

Comment: Is problem still present? Request, query and controller look fine.

Comment: Agreed, everything looks ok, can you run the code again? Maybe there is a new different error?

Comment: @jibiel Maybe it's the models then? I have updated my question above. I have a many-to-many relation between Requests and Brokers, and the link should be the Quotes model, where a Broker may enter a quote value and note for a particular Request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `Quote` is a join model for `Broker` and `Request` then it should have `broker_id` and `request_id` attributes and corresponding columns in database — http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

According to the schema you provided us with it's not a join table yet.
And you should specify above mentioned parameters in your request.

Comment: I removed the table mapping (belongs_to, has_many) and am still getting the same error.

Comment: I re-created a new scaffold called Q (for Quotes) and set the float type to decimal. It is now working fine with this new model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an activerecord method called 'quote' that may be interfering.  You can look in activerecord by doing a `bundle open activerecord` from the command line and looking in the lib/sanitization.rb file on line 190.  I suspect your 'quote' method and the activerecord method collided.

Here is a list of reserved words in rails.  "Quote cannot be used as a column name"

http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/

Renaming your class will fix this if it's the case.